# Find ID name of sibling element and add to href

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a long document with a lot of sub-sections and would like to automate some steps with some JS. (It's a static page in a rudimentary CMS.)

I have lots of this:

```
<div class="title">
  <h3 id="oranges">Oranges are great</h3>
  <a href="XXXX" class="url">Link to this section</a>
</div>

<div class="title">
  <h3 id="apples">Apples are great</h3>
  <a href="XXXX" class="url">Link to this section</a>
</div>
```

What I'd like to do is grab the ID name of the H3 and automatically insert it as an anchor in the href="" of the link. Is this possible?

So the link (.url) has "#organges" or "#apples" as a href, if that makes sense.

jQuery is already loaded, if that makes it easier.

Comment: Iterate through all your `h3` tags, take their `id`, refer to their parent to refer from there to the `a` tag child and then fill `href` with `attr()`. So yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion (Vanilla JS):

```js
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('.title');

for (var div of divs) {
  var el = div.children;
  el[1].href = '#' + el[0].id;
};
```

```html
<div class="title">
  <h3 id="oranges">Oranges are great</h3>
  <a href="XXXX">Link to this section</a>
</div>
<div class="title">
  <h3 id="apples">Apples are great</h3>
  <a href="XXXX">Link to this section</a>
</div>
<div class="title">
  <h3 id="cherries">Cherries are great</h3>
  <a href="XXXX">Link to this section</a>
</div>
```

**EDIT #1 (2021-08-29)**

Assuming that, in your HTML code, `<a>` (whatever its "class" may be) comes always right after `<h3>`, you can alternatively do this:

```js
var els = document.querySelectorAll('.title h3');

for (var el of els) el.nextElementSibling.href = '#' + el.id;
```

```html
<div class="title">
  <h3 id="oranges">Oranges are great</h3>
  <a href="XXXX">Link to this section</a>
</div>
<div class="title">
  <h3 id="apples">Apples are great</h3>
  <a href="XXXX">Link to this section</a>
</div>
<div class="title">
  <h3 id="cherries">Cherries are great</h3>
  <a href="XXXX">Link to this section</a>
</div>
```

**EDIT #2 (2021-08-30)**

Following your last comment:

```js
var els = document.querySelectorAll('.title');

for (var el of els) el.querySelector('.url').href = '#' + el.querySelector('h3').id;
```

```html
<div class="title">
  <h3 id="oranges">Oranges are great</h3>
  <a href="XXXX" class="url">Link to this section</a>
</div>
<div class="title">
  <h3 id="apples">Apples are great</h3>
  <a href="XXXX" class="url">Link to this section</a>
</div>
<div class="title">
  <h3 id="cherries">Cherries are great</h3>
  <a href="XXXX" class="url">Link to this section</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! If I wanted to target the link with the class .url and the H3 specifically (see original post), how would I adapt this? There are other elements within the div with the class .title.

Comment: Thanks for your help! But as mentioned, there are other elements in the DIV and I can't guarantee the order of H3 and a elements, so ideally I'd like to target the h3 and the link with the class 'url' specifically. Is that possible?

Comment: @Kai See edit #2. Please accept and upvote my answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 2):

Since ids are unique, either you have to loop though div with class name title or loop though tag name, Even you can assign class name to the tag h3. Getting elements `by class name` will be more prefered than `by tagname` to reduce the human errors. Vannilla JS is my personal preference and suggestion

```js
var div = document.querySelectorAll(".title h3"); // or classname can be oranges
div.forEach(function(slide, index) {
    let id_ = slide.getAttribute('id')
    slide.nextElementSibling.href = '#' + id_;
    console.log(slide.nextElementSibling.href)
});
```

```html
<div class="title">
  <h3 id="oranges">Oranges are great</h3>
  <a href="XXXX">Link to this section</a>
</div>
<div class="title">
  <h3 id="oranges2">Oranges are great</h3>
  <a href="XXXX">Link to this section</a>
</div>
```

**Method 2**

Loop by tagName

```js
var div = document.querySelectorAll("h3"); // or classname can be oranges
div.forEach(function(slide, index) {
    let id_ = slide.getAttribute('id')
    slide.nextElementSibling.href = '#' + id_;
    console.log(slide.nextElementSibling.href)
});
```

```html
<div class="title">
  <h3 id="oranges">Oranges are great</h3>
  <a href="XXXX">Link to this section</a>
</div>
<div class="title">
  <h3 id="oranges2">Oranges are great</h3>
  <a href="XXXX">Link to this section</a>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

```js
var div = document.querySelectorAll(".title h3"); // or classname can be oranges
div.forEach(function(slide, index) {
    let id_ = slide.getAttribute('id')
    slide.nextElementSibling.href = '#' + id_;
    slide.nextElementSibling.className = 'url';
    console.log(slide.nextElementSibling)
});
```

```html
<div class="title">
  <h3 id="oranges">Oranges are great</h3>
  <a href="XXXX">Link to this section</a>
</div>
<div class="title">
  <h3 id="apples">Apples are tasty</h3>
  <a href="XXXX">Link to this section</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I used the first method and it seems to work, although it's missing the # for an anchor. How do I add that?

Comment: Sorry, another question: instead of using Element.previousElementSibling, if I give the link tag a class, say '.url', how would I change the code to target the link?

Comment: @Kai, can you please edit comment to more understandable, i was not able to get the point

Comment: I made a couple of changes to the original post. Can you see what I'm trying to do now? I want to insert the ID into the link with the class .url as an anchor.

Comment: @Kai You mean, you have to add class name additionaly

Comment: Yes, I would like to target the link by class name (.url) inside the .title div. I just implemented your script, but it only works for the first .title div, not subsequent ones, unfortunately. There are many .title divs on one page.

Comment: @Kai, Please updated answer, it woks for all elements

Comment: Great, it works! Thank you! Is there a way to avoid 'nextElementSibling' entirely and find the element somewhere inside the div 'title' purely based on the class name 'url'?

Comment: Yes sure, try to get `var assign = document.querySelectorAll('.title');` and loop through it access the key (`0,1`) of `children` from the object of elements

Answer (score 0):

Inside the loop, catch `h3` id, find next anchor element using `$(this).next('a')` and set URL attribute `attr("href", url)` and text `.text(rid);`.

Example:

```js
$('.fruits').each(function(index, element) {
  var rid = $(this).attr("id");
  var url = "https://example.com?id=" + rid;
  $(this).next('a').attr("href", url).text(rid);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="title">
  <h3 class="fruits" id="oranges">Oranges are great</h3>
  <a href="XXXX">Link to this section</a>
</div>
<div class="title1">
  <h3 class="fruits" id="oranges1">Oranges1 are great</h3>
  <a href="XXXX">Link to this section</a>
</div>
```

Note: Id must be unique so I am using class for loop .

Answer (score 0):

Vanilla JS. Assumptions: No pre-defined a tags and ids must be unique.

```
var elems = document.body.getElementsByTagName("h3");
for (i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
  const anchor = document.createElement('a');
  const parent = elems[i].parentNode;
  anchor.href= "#" + elems[i].id;
  anchor.innerText = "Anchor to Section " + (i+1);
  console.log(parent);
  elems[i].parentNode.insertBefore(anchor,elems[i].nextSibling);
}
```